# Как запустить проект Django на другой машине?

Tags: django

Только начинаю изучать Django, столкнулся с такой проблемой...

На одном из компьютеров создал проект, внутренние ссылки работают. Перенес файл проекта на другой компьютер, установил Django, запустил сервер, при переходе на *127.0.0.1:8000* сайт загружается. А вот при переходе по внутренним ссылкам, ошибка 404. Подскажите с чем это связано?

Я сделал так:

1. Скопировал папку на другой компьютер
2. С помощью pip установил Джангу (совпадают ли версии или нет, могу узнать только вечером, если это принципиально )
3. Запустил джанго из командной строки Windows...

Попробовал сделать так:

В главном `urls` изменил

```
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

на

```
url(r'^', admin.site.urls),
```

И тогда я вошел в админку по ссылке первого уровня... При этом попробовала создать новое приложение.

1. Выполнил startapp в консоли
2. В settings прописал приложение 'F2',
3. В `urls`
   url(r'^F/', include('webexample.urls')),

Пробую зайти по ссылке *http://127.0.0.1:8000/F2* - ошибка 404

Пробовал даже так:

```
url(r'^F/', admin.site.urls),
```

Не работает..

Но почему же так:

```
url(r'^', admin.site.urls),
```

тогда работает?

То есть по ссылке первого уровня все работает... А по ссылке второго уровня нет:(

Вот полный текст ошибки из браузера:

> ```
> Page not found (404)
> Request Method:   GET
> Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/news
> Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>
> ^admin/
> ^ ^$ [name='index']
> ^ ^contact/ [name='contact']
> ^webexample/
> ^news/
> The current path, news, didn't match any of these.
>
> You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
> ```

Comment: Так `/news` или `/news/`?

Comment: Думаю дело все таки не в этом...

Comment: Возможно и не в этом, но всё ж нужно не думать, а пробовать и проверять - поиграться-то с /news и /news/ не пробовали на всякий случай?

Comment: Не пробовал. Поиграться и так хватает с чем:( Сейчас например пытаюсь освоить подключение статических файлов:( А вообще думаю правильно так должно записываться /news/ ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

И все таки причина была в конфликте версий DJango... Ранее я использовал 1.9.1, а на новой машине установил по умолчанию самую новую 2.1.1.... Видимо есть в них кардинальная разница:(

Что то не чего понять не могу. В общем переустанавливал эти две версии джанго в итоге у меня на версии 2.1.1 вес работает, хотя в файлах не чего не менял... 
Единственную разницу которую заметил между версиями 1.9.1 и 2.1.1, это то что в урлах ссылки по разному прописаны, в 1.9.1 вот так:

```
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

А в 2.1.1:

```
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

Comment: Даже между 1.9 и 1.10 много разницы, а между 1.9 и 2.1 вообще оооооооочень-очень много. Нужно использовать именно ту версию, для которой делался сайт